# Constant errors with check constraint in MS Access using SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm creating the table with this command:

```
CREATE TABLE Comp (
SerialNumber Number Primary Key Not Null,
Make Text(12) Not Null,
Model Text(24) Not Null,
ProcessorType Text(24) Null,
ProcessorSpeed Int Not Null,
MainMemory Text(15) Not Null,
DiskSize Text(15) Not Null
);
```

Which works I then try to add the constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE Comp
ADD CONSTRAINT CheckSpeed
CHECK (ProcessorSpeed > 0);
```

Which returns the error: "Syntax Error in CONSTRAINT Clause".
I've tried adding:

```
CHECK (ProcessorSpeed > 0)
```

To the table creation command but it returns the same error. Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: It would appear that Access doesn't allow for `CHECK` constraints in SQL. Only `PRIMARY KEY`, `FOREIGN KEY` and `UNIQUE` constraints are listed in the *documentation* for the [`CONSTRAINT` clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb177889(v=office.12).aspx)

Comment: I believe this can be achieved with something Access calls "Validation Rules" instead: http://allenbrowne.com/ValidationRule.html

Comment: Thanks the help, it was working in MySql but not Access due to the reasons Damien stated. Interestingly enough the book I was using provides the CHECK statement and doesn't inform you that you can't use it in Access even though the book is based on learning Access.

Comment: MySQL has no `CHECK` constraints. It only parses them in table's CREATE but ignores them. Completely.

Comment: `ALTER TABLE Comp ADD CONSTRAINT CheckSpeed CHECK (ProcessorSpeed > 0);` works fine in an Access-2003 installation I have found lying in an old pc.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever That is simply not true and I have no idea why your comment should be upvoted. You will even find an article on MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa140015(office.10).aspx#acintsql_ddlconst

Comment: And another link: [How to: Modify a Table's Design Using Access SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb243857(v=office.12).aspx)

Comment: @Remou - I did say "it would appear...", and *most* of the documentation fails to include `CHECK` as a valid option for `CONSTRAINT` clauses.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Mmhm? Define most.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to run against a connection and Comp is a reserved word.

```
ss = "ALTER TABLE [Comp] ADD CONSTRAINT CheckSpeed CHECK (ProcessorSpeed > 0)"
CurrentProject.Connection.Execute ss
```

Info: [Constraints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa140015%28office.10%29.aspx#acintsql_ddlconst)

Reserved words in [Jet/Access pre 2007](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/248738) and [ACE/Access 2007-](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208875%28v=office.12%29.aspx)

Comment: Nice! The only thing I didn't test, was if `Comp` is reserved.